# how to upgrade mongodb 2.2 to 2.4 properly

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I have a community edition mongodb of 2.2 version and I have read this article: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/

However, I got following errors when I tried to follow the above instruction:

```
Transaction Check Error:
 file /usr/bin/bsondump from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongo from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongodump from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongoexport from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongofiles from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongoimport from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongooplog from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongoperf from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongorestore from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongostat from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/mongotop from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

System: Fedora 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to their repo for downloads that old:
http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/

Pick your distro (for example, if Ubuntu pick Debian), drill in to the arch (x86/x64) and pick your download.

example:
Ubuntu 64 bit 2.4 download:
http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/mongodb-10gen_2.4.14_amd64.deb

Try to always go for the latest release of any numbered version (the link is for 2.4.14) and avoid .0 versions (such as 2.4.0).

Comment: I get error when I tried to install this: `Transaction Check Error:file /usr/bin/bsondump from install of mongo-10gen-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongodb-2.2.3-4.fc17.x86_64`  any ideas?

Comment: Do you already install a different version of mongo on this server and are you running as sudo?

Comment: Yep, there's already a mongodb 2.2 running on this machine, and that's why I need a upgrade. And yes, I ran as sudo

Comment: @Henry hey did you still need help on this? I was out.

Comment: Razephi    it's done. thx. I just dump the data, remove the old one, install 2.4 version

Comment: Perfect.  That'll work.